# Using tkinter IntVar to update a label

Tags: python, tkinter

Having taken a class on C and Assembly, I decided I wanted to learn python.  This is my first attempt with it so please excuse any abuse of notation.
The following is the portion of my GUI I have created to control a grow cycle.  I am having an issue with the use IntVar.  I have created a countdown to the end-of-cycle (see countdown method).  I have tried including the self.remaining label within Countdown, it does show the countdown but the label showing the countdown does not destroy with the cancel button and time_state label at end-of-cycle.  With the self.remaining label put in the **init** using IntVar, it shows the initial countdown in days,hours, mins,secs but stays with that initial value and does not update as countdown is repeated.  Shouldn't using IntVar this way update the day_val, hour_val, min_val, and sec_val in the self.remaining label?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
class Grow_Cycle():
    def __init__(self): 
        self.time_state = Label(app, text = ("You have selected:\n     "+str(day_val)+" days,\n "+str(hour_val)+" hours,\n "+str(min_val)+" minutes"))
        self.time_state.grid(column = 1, row =1)
        self.bttn_3 = Button(app, text = "Cancel", command = self.cancel)
        self.bttn_3.configure(bg = "red")
        self.bttn_3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, 
                         ipadx = 50, ipady = 20,
                         padx = 20, pady = 100)
        self.temp1 = (day_val * 86400)+(hour_val * 3600)+(min_val * 60)
        self.countdown()                                        
        self.remaining = Label(app, text = ("You have remaining:\n"+str(day_lef.get())+" days,\n"
                                        +str(hour_lef.get())+" hours,\n"
                                        +str(min_lef.get())+" minutes,\n"
                                        +str(sec_lef.get())+" seconds"),
                                        textvariable = (day_lef, hour_lef, min_lef, sec_lef))                                            
        self.remaining.grid(column = 1, row = 2)             
    def cancel(self):
        self.remaining.destroy()
        self.bttn_3.destroy()
        self.time_state.destroy()
        self.temp1 = 0        
def countdown(self):
    if self.temp1 > 0:
        self.temp1 -= 1            
        global day_lef
        day_lef = IntVar()
        day_lef.set(int(self.temp1 / 86400))
        day_rem = self.temp1 % 86400            
        global hour_lef
        hour_lef = IntVar()
        hour_lef.set(int(day_rem / 3600))
        hour_rem = day_rem % 3600            
        global min_lef
        min_lef = IntVar()
        min_lef.set(int(hour_rem / 60))
        min_rem = hour_rem % 60            
        global sec_lef
        sec_lef = IntVar()
        sec_lef.set(int(min_rem % 60))                        
        clock.after(1000, self.countdown)                  
    else:
        self.cancel()   
def tick():
    global time1
    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S\n\n%m-%d-%Y')
    if time2 != time1:
        time1 = time2
        clock.config(text=time2)
    clock.after(200, tick)       
def grow():
    # Grow Time set window
    set_grow_time = Toplevel(app)
    set_grow_time.title("Enter Cycle Time")
    set_grow_time.geometry("240x400")
    # Set Day
    set_day_grow = Spinbox(set_grow_time, from_ = 0, to_ = 10)
    set_day_grow.grid(column = 0, row =0,
                      padx = 20, pady = 20)
    set_day_grow.config(width = 10)
    set_day_lbl = Label(set_grow_time, text = "Set Day: 0 to 10")
    set_day_lbl.grid(column = 1, row = 0)    
    # Set Hour
    set_hour_grow = Spinbox(set_grow_time, from_ = 0, to_ = 23)
    set_hour_grow.grid(column = 0, row = 1,
                       padx = 20, pady = 20)
    set_hour_grow.config(width = 10)
    set_hour_lbl = Label(set_grow_time, text = "Set Hour: 0 to 23")
    set_hour_lbl.grid(column = 1, row = 1)    
    # Set Minute
    set_min_grow = Spinbox(set_grow_time, from_ = 0, to_ = 59)
    set_min_grow.grid(column = 0, row = 2,
                      padx = 20, pady = 20)
    set_min_grow.config(width = 10)
    set_hour_lbl = Label(set_grow_time, text = "Set Minute: 0 to 59")
    set_hour_lbl.grid(column = 1, row = 2)    
    # Confirm Selection
    def fetch_time():
        global day_val
        day_val = int(set_day_grow.get())
        global hour_val 
        hour_val = int(set_hour_grow.get())
        global min_val
        min_val = int(set_min_grow.get())
        Grow_Cycle()        
    confirm_grow_time = Button(set_grow_time, text = "OK", command = lambda: (fetch_time(), set_grow_time.destroy()))
    confirm_grow_time.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
    cancel_grow_time = Button(set_grow_time, text = "Cancel", command = set_grow_time.destroy)
    cancel_grow_time.grid(column = 1, row = 3)         
def clean():
    pass # will finish later
def cancel():
    pass # will finish later       
# main
# Main Loop Begin
root = Tk()
root.title("Grower")
root.geometry("1280x720")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
time1 = ''
clock = Label(app)
clock.config(font = ("Impact", 20))
clock.grid(column = 1, row = 0,
           ipadx = 20, ipady = 20,
           padx = 50, pady =50)
# Button Setup
bttn_1 = Button(app, text = "Grow", command = grow)
bttn_1.configure(bg = "light green")
bttn_1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, 
            ipadx = 50, ipady = 20,
            padx = 20, pady = 100)
bttn_2 = Button(app, text = "Clean", command = clean)
bttn_2.configure(bg = "cyan")
bttn_2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, 
           ipadx = 50, ipady = 20,
           padx = 20, pady = 100)

tick()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please fix your indention and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). we have no way of knowing how you are getting the variables day_val, hour_val, or min_val

Comment: You are using `global` in classes. Global variables are best avoided and you would be best off using class attributes.

Comment: you are creating new intvars every second, but you never use them for anything.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code I have made some changes to how you are formatting your strings and how you are apply strings to your labels.

Your class def was not working for me so I rewrote it with a standard method I use to create a tkinter class.

I don't believe you can have both a `text = "string'` and a `textvariable = StringVar()` at the same time. So I have formatted the data into your string var.

The way you had it set up it would not work for a few reason. You cant use multiple IntVar()'s in a textvariable so you need to first combine them into a string variable and then use that as your update method to the label.

I have changed your string concatination removing the `+` method and using `format()` instead as this is the correct method currently.

I also added `self.string_var.set` to your `countdown()` method so we can keep this updated with the countdown.

Take a look at this code and let me know if you have any question.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Grow_Cycle(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master

        self.day_val = 1
        self.hour_val = 0
        self.min_val = 0

        self.day_lef = tk.IntVar()
        self.day_lef.set(1)
        self.hour_lef = tk.IntVar()
        self.hour_lef.set(0)
        self.min_lef = tk.IntVar()
        self.min_lef.set(0)
        self.sec_lef = tk.IntVar()
        self.sec_lef.set(0)

        self.day_rem = 0
        self.hour_rem = 0
        self.min_rem = 0

        self.string_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.string_var2 = tk.StringVar()

        self.string_var.set(
            "You have remaining:\n{} days,\n{} hours,\n{} minutes,\n{} seconds".format(self.day_lef.get(), self.hour_lef.get(), self.min_lef.get(), self.sec_lef.get()))

        self.time_state = tk.Label(self.master, text = (
            "You have selected:\n {} days,\n {} hours,\n {} minutes").format(self.day_val, self.hour_val, self.min_val))
        self.time_state.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.bttn_3 = tk.Button(self.master, bg = "red", text = "Cancel", command = self.cancel)
        self.bttn_3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, ipadx = 50, ipady = 20, padx = 20, pady = 100)
        self.temp1 = (self.day_val * 86400)+(self.hour_val * 3600)+(self.min_val * 60)

        self.remaining = tk.Label(self.master, textvariable = self.string_var)
        self.remaining.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

        self.countdown()

    def cancel(self):
        self.remaining.destroy()
        self.bttn_3.destroy()
        self.time_state.destroy()
        self.temp1 = 0

    def countdown(self):
        self.string_var.set(
            "You have remaining:\n{} days,\n{} hours,\n{} minutes,\n{} seconds".format(self.day_lef.get(), self.hour_lef.get(), self.min_lef.get(), self.sec_lef.get()))

        if self.temp1 > 0:
            self.temp1 -= 1

            self.day_lef.set(int(self.temp1 / 86400))
            self.day_rem = self.temp1 % 86400

            self.hour_lef.set(int(self.day_rem / 3600))
            self.hour_rem = self.day_rem % 3600

            self.min_lef.set(int(self.hour_rem / 60))
            self.min_rem = self.hour_rem % 60

            self.sec_lef.set(int(self.min_rem % 60)) 

            root.after(1000, self.countdown)                  
        else:
            self.cancel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Grow_Cycle(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I updated the code so you can get a better idea of what i was trying to do.  Looking at your code, I'll definitely give that a shot.  I was using global variables in case I wound up needing them somewhere else in parts I haven't done yet but I see how using class attributes would be good.  Is the use of globals a programming etiquette deal or is there deeper meaning?

Comment: It's considered bad practice in any programming languages. There are a few good reason to not use global variables. You will find several post on the topic here on stack overflow